# Sending mail via shell script

Tags: email, shell, command

I want to send a zip file via email on shell script. I know I need to use the following command:

```
cat file.txt | mail -s "This is subject" [email]name@address.com[/email]
```

I always get this error:

```
line 13: mail: command not found
```

Does anyone know where and how I can install the mail command?

I am using Cygwin to test my shell script.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in ubuntu, you can use *apt*

```
sudo apt-get install mailutils postfix
```

Comment: Nope. I am on Cygwin whih provides a linux layer on top of windows. I got "sudo: command not found" error.

Comment: yeah you don't have apt for cygwin. You have to use the installer (called `setup.exe`) and search for the packages there.

Answer (score 0):

Install the "nail" or "mailx" package.